# Kotlin and Retrofit : How to Handle HTTP 400 responses?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I am using Retrofit (2.6) on Android to implement a service which connects to a web server, and which requests that the server undertake some work. The relevant code can be summarized thus:

```
interface MyService {
    @GET(START_WORK)
    suspend fun startWork(@Query("uuid") uuid: String,
                          @Query("mode") mode: Int):
        MyStartWorkResponse
}

// Do some other things, include get a reference to a properly configured
// instance of Retrofit.

// Instantiate service
var service: MyService = retrofit.create(MyService::class.java)
```

I can call `service.startWork()` with no problem and obtain valid results.  However, in some conditions, the web server will return a 400 error code, with a response body which includes specific error information. The request is not malformed, however; it's just that there is another problem which should be brought to the user's attention. The trouble is, I can't tell what the problem is, because I don't get a response; instead, my call throws an exception because of the 400 error code.

I don't understand how to modify my code so that I can catch and handle 400 error responses, and get the information I need from the body of the response. Is this a job for a network interceptor on my okhttp client?  Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit defines successful response as such:

> public boolean isSuccessful() {
>       return code >= 200 && code < 300;   }

which means you should be able to do something like this

```
class ServiceImpl(private val myService: MyService) {
   suspend fun startWork(//query): MyResponse =

    myService.startWork(query).await().let {

    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        return MyResponse(response.body()//transform
                ?: //some empty object)
    } else {
        throw HttpException(response)//or handle - whatever
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I don't see how I am able to hook into Retrofit to get a reference to `response`, though. by the time we get to this point, won't the call have failed already?

Comment: it would fail but not throw an exception - and you should be able to read the body via errorBody - public static <T> Response<T> error(ResponseBody body, okhttp3.Response rawResponse) {
    checkNotNull(body, "body == null");
    checkNotNull(rawResponse, "rawResponse == null");
    if (rawResponse.isSuccessful()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rawResponse should not be successful response");
    }
    return new Response<>(rawResponse, null, body);
  }

Comment: What would `MyResponse` need to inherit from in order for me to call `await()` and `response.isSuccessful` ?

Comment: MyResponse is your custom model - you transform. Overall here is an example of the structure: /service
interface MyService {

    @GET( "whatever")
    fun getSomething(@Query(value="whatever) id: Int): Deferred<List<MyModel>>

}

//repository
interface MyRepository  {
    suspend fun getSomething(id: Int): List<MyModel>

}

//repos impl
class MyRepositoryImpl (private val myService: MyService) : MyRepository {

    override suspend fun getSomething(id: Int): List<MyModel> =
            myService.getSomething(id).await().let {
                it
            }
}

Comment: here is a great example of this pattern - https://github.com/fabioCollini/ArchitectureComponentsDemo/blob/master/api/src/main/java/it/codingjam/github/api/GithubRepositoryImpl.kt

Answer (score 1):

Use this code (KOTLIN)

```
class ApiClient {

    companion object {

        private val BASE_URL = "YOUR_URL_SERVER"
        private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

        private val okHttpClientvalor = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        fun apiClient(): Retrofit {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClientvalor)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            }
            return retrofit!!
        }

    }

}


object ErrorUtils {

    fun parseError(response: Response<*>): ErrorResponce? {
        val conversorDeErro = ApiClient.apiClient()
            .responseBodyConverter<ErrorResponce>(ErrorResponce::class.java, arrayOfNulls(0))
        var errorResponce: ErrorResponce? = null
        try {
            if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                errorResponce = conversorDeErro.convert(response.errorBody()!!)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            return ErrorResponce()
        } finally {
            return errorResponce
        }
    }
}


class ErrorResponce {
     /* This name "error" must match the message key returned by the server.
  Example: {"error": "Bad Request ....."} */
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    var error: String? = null
}

    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        return MyResponse(response.body()  // transform
                ?:  // some empty object)
    } else {
        val errorResponce = ErrorUtils.parseError(response)
        errorResponce!!.error?.let { message ->
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```